# Python-Mysql, better lib or better approach?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using mysql.connector and for some tasks, for example insert data in a local mysql database the process is taken 0.0436846 s. average, there are some way to improve it?

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
    class Dal:
        @profile
        def __init__(self, dic):
            try:
                self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=dic['user'],
                                    password=dic['password'],
                                    host=dic['host'],
                                    database=dic['database'])
            self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()

            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                    print("User/Pass Fails")
                elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                    print("BD no exist")
                else:
                    print(err)


        def insert_event(self,dic):
            ins_ev = ("INSERT INTO events "
                        "(device, type, index, datetime, c1,\
                         c2, vel, head, pfm, age,vod,created_on ) "
                        "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                        )
            self.cursor.execute(ins_ev, dic)
            self.cnx.commit()
```

Maybe another approach?

Comment: Why do you need to improve it?  What would be a meaningful improvement?  Is there any opportunity to batch insertion of events together, or can they really only be done piecemeal one by one in the context of your system?  Is the time the insert takes a problem directly, or is this more of a problem with responsiveness of the caller, so you might be able to address your problem by threading the actual insert operation?

Comment: they really be done, one by one...only, maybe somebody did deal with a better way to do that...

Comment: Your question is equivalent to, "it takes me too long to get to the store, how can I get my shopping done faster?"  It's pretty hard to give you an answer unless we have enough information to tell if you could use an alternate route, driver faster, send someone else instead, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql.connector` is a pure Python module. Either of MySQL-python or oursql, which link against the C library, should give you better performance for at least the communications part. Other optimizations include disabling indexes and performing lazy inserts.